# In Android how to delete the entire record in Table without passing any arguments?

Tags: android, database, delete-row

Hai i created a DataBase and inserted the value in one Class,and i try to delete the record in another class but,the Whole table is Deleted.i need to delete the entire record only without deleteing the table.is it possible to delete all record without any condition?
kindly help me
Thanks in advance

```
public void deletePayment()
{

    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE3, "KEY_ROLLID=?",null);//i want to delete all row in KEY_ROLLID
}
```

Comment: db.delete(tablename, null, null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doesn't try DELETE Statement,

In android you can execute Sql Query with db.rawQuery also, in this you can pass Delete Statement for your table, as:

db.rawQuery("Delete FROM Table_Name");

Answer (score 0):

Use this concept:

```
public static void deletedatafromtable(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            SQLiteDatabase SQLITE_db;

            SQLITE_db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("databaseName",
                    SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

            SQLITE_db.setVersion(1);
            SQLITE_db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            SQLITE_db.setLockingEnabled(true);

            String DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL = "delete from tableName;";
            SQLITE_db.execSQL(DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL);

            SQLITE_db.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its working locally only But i applying into my Project.Its not Working

Comment: when you will call this funcation then pass the "getApplicationContext()", nothing else, I think, it's working fine.